# Spring boot project not generating Pom.xml file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, pom.xml

I am creating a spring boot project and it is not creating pom.xml file. I have attached the image below. I am new to spring boot so not sure about this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9Ivl.png)

Comment: You made a project that uses gradle as its build automation tool. The tutorial you are (probably) following is using maven.

Answer (score 2):

When visiting https://start.spring.io/
In the first row, you have **Project** with two options Gradle and Maven.

You have selected Gradle.

Create a new one just make sure that you select Maven instead of Gradle.

Gradle has build.gradle file, Maven has pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a project with a maven otherwise the project don't create POM.xml file

Answer (score 0):

At https://start.spring.io/ you have to select Maven in the Project to get the `pom.xml` file.

[image: spring initializr]

Answer (score -1):

If the IDE you are using is eclipse,
Go to File -> New -> Spring Starter Project

Now in the new popup that opens up, make sure the **Type** is selected as **maven**.

[image: Spring Starter Project Window]